# Get specific xml lines with linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML looking like this:

```
<data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<row>
     <Alert>warning</Alert>
</row>
</data>
```

I wan't to get all the rows. In this case, the value that I wan't is "Alert".

This is as fare as I've got...

```
using (XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
            {
                string xmlFile = "";
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    xmlFile = reader.ReadOuterXml();
                }
                var xmlElement = XElement.Parse(xmlFile);
                var result = xmlElement.Elements("data").Where(x => x.Value.Equals("row")).ToList();
            }
```

I know something is wrong with my linq, but I'm quite new to linq and would like some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
var xDocument = XDocument.Load("path");
var result = xDocument.Descendants(ns + "row").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work. Please try this.

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Load(@"XmlFilePath"); 
//Use below if you have xml in string format
// var xDocument = XDocument.Parse("XmlString"); 
XNamespace ns = xDocument.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var result = xDocument.Descendants(ns + "row").ToList();
```